# Display a dicom image in qt5.7 (C++) with VTK 7

Tags: c++, qt

I need to display a dicom image for my project. I have qt5.7. I downloaded VTK7 and I build it with CMake and microsoft visual studio 15. I followed the tutorial here : http://hxr99.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/qt-vtk-displaying-single-dicom-file.html

However, it is not working.

I get this kinds of error : 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\VTK-7.0.0\Common\Core\vtkSmartPointer.h:26: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'

What am i missing??

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `_imp___ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev` looks like a gcc mangling. You should make sure that everything is built with gcc or that everything is built with the visual studio.